# How to prove that there is closure in NP for the reverse operation on strings?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, computer-science, formal-languages, np-complete

I have a language A which is known to be in NP. I want to know that if I have the language $A^R$ which takes in $w^R$ which is a word of A but read in reverse will it still be in NP?

I tried to prove it by writing that: because A is in NP we have a certificat c and therefore a polynomial verificator. I therefore conclude that we can build another polynomial verificator V which will take in $w^R$ which is w read in reverse and $c^R$ which is the certificat of A but read in reverse. Because we can make V we conclude that $A^R$ is in NP.

Does my proof make sense or there is presence of circular reasoning? What should I do to have a correct proof or a more formal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: work directly with the definition of NP noting that you can reverse the contents of the input tape of a Turing machine in polynomial time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I do we just reverse the input? How about the states of the Turing machine? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: You are given that $A$ is recognisable by a non-deterministic Turing machine, $T_0$ say, in polynomial time. You can construct a Turing machine $T_1$ that first reverses its input tape in polynomial time and then processes the input tape just as $T_0$ would. $T_1$ is a non-deterministic Turing machine that recognises $A^R$ in polynomial time. This just requires modifying the halting state of a Turing machine that reverses the input (and has no states in common with $T_0$) to be the starting state of $T_0$.

Comment: I'm a not allowed (In my homework) to use non-determinstic Turing machine for NP and must use polynomial verificators to make this proof. Do you have any hint with this approach instead?

Comment: Just use the same trick: the certificate that shows $\langle w_1, \ldots, w_n\rangle$ is in $A^R$ is the same as the certificate that show $\langle w_n, \ldots, w_1$ is in $A$ and the verifier for $A^R$ just reverses the contents of its tape after the certificate before verifying membership of $A$.

Comment: Just to be sure, is it the same thing I said in my question details?

Comment: You shouldn't reverse the certificate. Try going into a bit more detail about how the Turing machines involved.